# postgres was not the same version as pg_ctl in PostgreSQL 12

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql-12

As per the log files, I am getting the below errors.

> The program "postgres" was found by "/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl"
> but was not the same version as pg_ctl.
> Check your installation.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

I executed the following commands to determine which versions are running:

```bash
# /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres --version
```

> ```
> postgres (PostgreSQL) 12.16 (Ubuntu 12.16-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
> ```

```bash
# /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl --version
```

> ```
> pg_ctl (PostgreSQL) 12.15 (Ubuntu 12.15-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
> ```

Do I need to update or perform some tasks as the current situation has rendered my DB Server useless and I have some databases which I am not able to access?

---

Also, now when I run the command, I get this error:

```
postgres@tvsr-strapi:~$ psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
postgres@tvsr-strapi:~$
```

I have tried recreating the symbolic link, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Everything was working perfectly fine but then all of a sudden I am seeing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was not able to restart my PostgreSQL Server, I decided to copy the data  files located in `/etc/postgresql/12/main` to another server and check if it works.

While trying to test this on a new Server, I installed the same version of PostgreSQL 12 and then tried checking the version info of the **pg_ctl** and **postgres**.

```
postgres (PostgreSQL) 12.16 (Ubuntu 12.16-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)

pg_ctl (PostgreSQL) 12.16 (Ubuntu 12.16-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
```

I was surprised to see that the versions were same unlike in my present server. So, I decided to simply copy the binary files from my new server to my old one from the location `/var/lib/postgresql/12`.

Once this was done, my PostgreSQL started without any issues or complaints. I know this may not be the best approach, but it worked and allowed me to take a dump of the data.

Although the question still remains as to how the version changed for the old server?